# ASP.NET Two Way Data Binding for simple object property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have struggled to find a clear and concise answer to this simple question.

Given an object property in the page named "SomeObj", is it possible for two way data binding like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="<%# SomeObj.SomeProperty %>" />
```

This will correctly display SomeProperty in the textbox if we call "this.DataBind()" in Page_Load. However, my object property is never written to during postback - have I done something wrong or is this actually not possible?

Should I put this control inside some container like FormView or DetailsView? At what point in the page life cycle should I be able to see my object property being written to?

All the thousands of copy-and-paste tutorials out there focus on lists and grids and binding to Sql Data Sources, which I do use successfully. But for a simple, single object surely there is a way that does not require extraneous containers, data sources and code-behind?

Of course the code to do this in code-behind for one text field is trivial, but no longer when multiplied by loads of properties and loads of pages. I have instead written two simple routines that use reflection to automatically load controls with property values and then save the control values back to the properties. With these routines we can then fill the page with simple markup like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="SomeObj_SomeProperty" runat="server" />
```

By simply naming the controls the same as the object property and calling my two methods at the appropriate times I get two-way data binding and the code-behind has very little code in it other than creating the main object, and I do not have to wrap the markup inside other controls just to get the data binding to work.

I am not very experienced with ASP.NET and it seems like I am doing something that should already be done for me.

**UPDATE:**

Note that if I try to use Bind() instead I get the usual data binding exception because there is no special data-binding control like a list or grid view:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SomeObj.SomeProperty") %>' />
```

Gives this error:

```
Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used 
in the context of a databound control.
```

Comment: Can't you just call the `Databind()` again whenever you want it updated?

Comment: Well I thought maybe DataBind() inside !IsPostBack would read the values and inside IsPostBack would write them but in each case it simply puts the object values into the control.

Comment: Have you debugged it and checked if the function to databind is called when there is a postback?

Comment: The debugger hits my property getter when I call DataBind() in Page_Load and the correct value is displayed in the text box. What I'm not understanding is how and when the DataBind() leads to writing the text box value back to my property. The debugger never hits the property setter.